# What was the point of having witnesses on patents?

Tags: usa, history

I see that some old USPTO patents list witnesses. [Example](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/bf/6f/51/2ee6d96e90af69/US659389.pdf):

[image]

What was the point of having witnesses on patents?

Comment: I can only guess that they are attesting that the document was signed by the inventor. Like witnesses on a will. Both are legal documents after all.